# SQL Server 2008 - cached sa password?

Tags: sql-server, caching, ssis

Something odd has happened earlier this week at work, and after researching and Googling for an answer, I am still none the wiser!

So hoping someone could shed some light on what might have occurred.

I look after a company's database and on Monday - I logged to check on things and all was ok.

The next day, a job failed to run,  on a step which updates the database using the 'sa' account - this now had a login failure.

So after checking the SQL Server logs, I can see that 20 minutes after I had logged off, the 'sa' had began to fail every 6 minutes.

So after speaking to the company they said they changed the 'sa' accounts password last Friday, and they had half expected this job to fail over the weekend, but it had taken until the following Tuesday to fail.

This doesn't make much sense to me - it sounds like the sa credentials had been cached, and when I opened and closed Management Studio on Monday, it had purged the cached credentials?

Does anyone perhaps know why this behaviour has occurred, an explanation would be absolutely awesome.  As it seems very strange to me right now!

Comment: You know using `sa` for anything other than admin is bad practice right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credentials, or the connections. Changing the SA password will not invalidate open connections. And if you have a lot of load from a server to the db with connection pooling enabled, connections can stay open for a LONG time.